Larave:Vite z index limit of 0? Why not -1
*this thread has evolved much today.
I am taking a basic php site I already have running and trying to understand why going to a framework was a good idea!
95% setup, using partials app.scss
Old index.php 2 images at z-1 and z-2 worked great.
Index.blade images are only visible at positive numbers.
using Vite and Laravel.
https://laravel_project.test/images/backgroundImage.jpg successfully brings up the image.
    }

.backgroundImage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: backgroundPan 10s linear infinite, backgroundFade 6s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.backgroundImage--blurred {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(20px);
  z-index: -2;
}

    <header>
    <div class="backgroundImage" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('images/backgroundImage.jpg') }}');"></div>
    <div class="backgroundImage--blurred" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('images/backgroundImage.jpg') }}');"></div>
    <div class="overlay--gradient"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>
            <div class="header__logo">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/headerLogo.png') }}" alt="International Brotherhood of Boilermakers Logo">
            </div>

